# Node.js + Express: Trying to Properly Display GET Request Headers

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm currently trying to write-up a simple echo server app that echoes back the the request headers when the server receives a GET request. It should look something like this:

[image: Echo Server]

Here is my routing code for the request:

```
app.get('/', function(req,res){
var s = '';
for(var name in req.headers) s += name + ': ' + req.headers[name] + '\n';
res.render('home', {output: s})});
```

It results in this response:

[image]

It seems that my newline character is not working as intended. I'm sure it's some silly mistake but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Since browser understands html only while rendering, you should use `<br />` instead of `\n` to split the lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to handle the new line character `\n` in html, you have to use the `<pre>` tag.

> The  tag defines preformatted text.
>
> Text in a  element is displayed in a fixed-width font (usually
>   Courier), and it preserves both spaces and **line breaks**.

```js
var values = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];

document.getElementById('no-newline').innerHTML = values.join('\n');
document.getElementById('newline').innerHTML = values.join('\n');
```

```html
<div id="no-newline"></div>
<pre id="newline"></div>
```

Otherwise use: `<br />` instead of `\n`

Comment: I completely forgot that I was going to be in HTML context when rendering the page, thanks for this.